# Как получить результат joina таблиц в spring?

Tags: java, mysql, веб-программирование, spring, freemarker

Имеется репозиторий, в нём есть запрос, содержащий в себе джоин.

В случае отсутствия джоина, я могу получать ответ от базы следующим образом:

```
public interface StudentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Students, Long> {
@Query(
        value= "select * from students",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<Students> findStudents();
```

т.е. засовывать в лист<сущность>, которую я потом отправляю через контроллер в модель, а оттуда забираю с помощью FreeMarker, с помощью которого я могу расставить на странице все полученные данные.

но как мне быть, если есть запрос с джоином? мне нужно как-то создать лист, чтобы из репозитория вставить туда ответ от базы? как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы что-то собираетесь джойнить у студента, то это, скорее всего, какие-то свойства этого студента, например, лист его скилов или что-то типа того. Значит, это свойство уже должно быть у вашего студента как `List<Skill> skills;`. Остается только аккуратно прописать эти все свойства в классе и настроить отношения.

Comment: А если я собираюсь джоинить разные таблицы?
Имеется база данных в стиле "электронный дневник", и там есть таблица со студентами, с оценками, с дисциплинами и т.д.
И мне нужно, например, вывести запрос, который выглядит как-то так:

        select subject, mark, date, reason from marks left join subjects on marks.subject_id=subjects.id; 

я так понимаю, мне нужно создавать что-то вроде отдельной сущности с такими полями?

Comment: Да, это отдельная сущность.